# Storybook demo using either react or angular not loading but no errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

I'm trying to get the getting started demos running for either angular or react and npm run storybook loads launches but the sidebar never loads, but just sort of blinks and on hover the blue loading circle spins endlessly.  There are no console errors so I'm not sure where to start debugging this. I used create react app to set up the project.

react setup

src/index.stories.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from '@storybook/react/demo';

export default { title: 'Button' };

export const withText = () => <Button>Hello Button</Button>;

export const withEmoji = () => (
    <Button>
    <span role="img" aria-label="so cool">
         
    </span>
    </Button>
);
```

src/storybook/main.js

```
module.exports = {
    stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.[tj]s'],
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "storybook": "start-storybook"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/react": "^5.3.18"
  }
}
```

What am I missing?